# looking for a shell for Javascript coding/experimenting using command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, ipython

Is there a shell for Javascript coding/experimenting using command line offering history, completion, help, debug, etc.? I found [iPython](http://ipython.org/) very useful for quick Python scripting.

I looked at various shells like [node](http://nodejs.org/), [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell), [JSDB](http://www.jsdb.org/), but their command line functionality seem to be somewhat limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console does exactly what you want, as does the Chrome Developer Tools (accessible by pressing F12 or by navigating through the menu).

Comment: There is also an experimental "terminal" plugin at:

http://paulrouget.com/e/jsterm/

Answer (score 0):

I use [kobyk's REPL](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-jscript-interactive-interpreter-shell-for-the-windows-script-host/) on cscript.exe.

Also, I use emacs, and there is an elisp module that allows hosting of that REPL in emacs, called [jsshell](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/jsshell-bundle).  This means you can do cut/paste, search/replace, command-line editing, and so on - all the text manipulation made available to emacs buffers is available in the interactive Javascript shell.

```
Welcome to the JScript shell.
Running JScript Version 5.8.16982
'exit' to exit.

js> 
loading c:\dev\js\json2.js
js> 

loading c:\dev\js\stringExtensions.js
js> 

loading c:\dev\js\moment.js
js> 

loading c:\dev\js\arrayExtensions.js
js> 
Multi-line input. Use two consecutive blank lines to eval.

var id = "11111;22222;33333"; 

id = id.split(";"); 

js> function say (x) {WScript.echo(x);}
js> for (var i in id) { say (i); } 
0
1
2
forEach
every
map
filter
remove
removeAt
indexOf
contains
js> for(var i=0;i<id.length;i++) { say (i + ": " + id[i]); } 
0: 11111
1: 22222
2: 33333
js>
```